# JQuery Select multiple paypal buttons

Tags: jquery

I want to have 2 paypal buttons selected by 1 select box.

I have a minimum form code:

//The Form

```
<form id="form1" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">


<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option id="option1" value="1">Button1</option>
    <option id="option2" value="2">Button2</option>
</select>

<input type="image" src="images/purchase_button.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online." />
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

then at runtime jquery would do the rest:

```
$('#select1').change(function () {

if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 1) {

    $('#button1').remove(); //clean up
    $('#button2').remove(); //clean up

    $('#form1').append('<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="button1-code-here" id="button1" />');


} else {

    $('#button1').remove(); //clean up
    $('#button2').remove(); //clean up

    $('#form1').append('<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="button2-code-here" id="button2" />');

}



});
```

My problem is that sometimes when I select option 1 button it's  submitting button 2.

Does paypal save cookies when you go to the paypal payment page?

When is this not working smoothly everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs some optimization. Make them and it will work as expected.

First **use 1 button**, there is no need for extra buttons as the only thing you need to do is *change the value*. With use of one button, your entire code can wrote in these simple lines.

```
$('#select1').change(function () {

    if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 1) {
        $("#button1").val("button-1-code");
    } else {
       $("#button1").val("button-2-code");
    }

});
```

---

And to answer your segregated questions:

> My problem is that sometimes when I select option 1 button it's submitting button 2.

The above solves this problem

> Does paypal save cookies when you go to the paypal payment page?

Sometimes, but you can't rely on this to develop your code

> When is this not working smoothly every time?

Above solution will again get it done

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it as below,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('#select1').on('change',(function ()
        {
            var id    = $(this).text();
            var value = $(this).val();
            $('#button1').remove();
            $('#button2').remove();

            $('#form1').append('<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="'+id+'-code-here" id="'+id+'" />');
        });
    });

</script>
```